# apt-get for installing lamp

Tags: linux, debian, apt, lamp

i am on a debian 6 at 64bit.

I need to install LAMP.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql php5-gd
```

are those command enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Ubuntu page for setting up LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP), yes, you are correct.  You could also use `tasksel` to setup the server:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

See the guide for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed:

- mysql-server
- mysql-client
- apache2 (depends on apache2-mpm-prefork)
- php5 (depends on libapache-mod-php5)
- php5-mysql
- php5-gd
- php5-suhosin (security module)

Depending on what you are doing in php you may need additional php modules.

Comment: if i forgot to install a php module.. How Can I add it later?

Comment: Use the command `sudo aptitude install` followed by the package name.  The aptitude package management tool has a text mode graphical interface if you like. You can also use the search and show command from the command line, `man aptitude` will give you more information.